# How can I generate image through php?

Tags: php

Hi I want to generate image through php, but it doesn't work. I do not know where is a mistake. This code should generate a rectangle 60x30px with number as text.

I also checked another questions on StackOverflow but it did not help me.

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$rand_num=rand(11111,99999);
$_SESSION['CODE']=$rand_num;
$layer=imagecreatetruecolor(60,30);
$captcha_bg=imagecolorallocate($layer,0,152,95);
imagefill($layer,0,0,$captcha_bg);
$captcha_text_color=imagecolorallocate($layer,255,255,255);
imagestring($layer,5,5,5,$rand_num,$captcha_text_color);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($layer);
?>
```

Comment: You could just use a real CAPTCHA option instead of something that won't ever work as a CAPTCHA.

Comment: What happens instead of functional code? At the top of your script, always in development, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and update your question with any errors PHP displays

Comment: The `image*()` functions require the gd extension, make sure you have that. I copied and pasted your code and it executed correctly as it is posted.

Comment: PHP displays no error.

@MichaelBerkowski I installed PHP-GD, how can I import gd extension? Just through import gd?

Comment: If gd is present and working you should get output, this code works. Just call `phpinfo();` and verify the extension is loaded. `extension=gd.so` must be in php.ini, and if you just installed it you might need to restart php-fpm or your web server before it is loaded.